# Count the number of files inside a folder in Objective C (Cocoa)

Tags: objective-c, image

I m making an array of images animate like a flicker book animation,i m storing these images inside a folder which intern resides inside Resource folder of my project in xcode..
these images will vary,that is why i have to determine the exact number of images inside the folder so how should i determine this? is there any API in cocoa to achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, you need to access the bundle path of your application:

```
 NSMutableString* bundlePath = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:4];
 [bundlePath appendString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]];
```

**Now append your folder name to the bundlePath**

```
 [bundlePath appendString:@"/MyFolder"];
 NSArray *directoryContent  = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:bundlePath error:nil];
 int numberOfFileInFolder = [directoryContent count];
```

Answer (score 16):

Try

```
int paths = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:@"/your/path/here" error:NIL] count];
```

For more info,
http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html